# Why it does not create object of Preference helper using Dagger 2

Tags: android

```
@Singleton
public class AppPreferenceHelper implements PreferenceHelper {
    static final String PREFS_APP_STATE = "prefsAppState";
    static final String APP_STATE_LOGIN = "logIn";
    String PREF_NAME ="appPreference" ;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Inject
    AppPreferenceHelper(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PreferenceConstant.PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void setAppState(String state) {
       sharedPreferences.edit().putString(PREFS_APP_STATE,state);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAppState() {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(PREFS_APP_STATE,APP_STATE_LOGIN);
    }

}


@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {


    void inject(SplashActivity mainActivity);
    void inject(LogInActivity logInActivity);
}
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final Application mApplication;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AppPreferenceHelper providePreferencesHelper(AppPreferenceHelper appPreferencesHelper) {
        return appPreferencesHelper;
    }

}
@Module
public class ActivityModule {
    private Activity mActivity;

    public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return mActivity;
    }

    @Provides
    Activity provideActivity`enter code here`() {
        return mActivity;
    }`enter code here`

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    SpashMvpPresenter<SplashView> provideSplashPresenter(
            SplashPresenter<SplashView> presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }

}
```

> Error:(20, 10) error: com.d2u.android.data.preference.PreferenceHelper
>   cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   com.d2u.android.data.preference.PreferenceHelper is injected at
>   com.d2u.android.ui.splash.SplashPresenter.(preferenceHelper)
>   com.d2u.android.ui.splash.SplashPresenter
>   is injected at
>   com.d2u.android.di.module.ActivityModule.provideSplashPresenter(presenter)
>   com.d2u.android.ui.splash.SpashMvpPresenter
>   is injected at com.d2u.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity.mPresenter
>   com.d2u.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity is injected at
>   com.d2u.android.di.component.ActivityComponent.inject(mainActivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably because you are injecting a `PreferenceHelper`, but your `@Provides` annotated method returns `AppPreferenceHelper` instead of `PreferenceHelper`

```
@Provides
PreferenceHelper providePreferencesHelper(AppPreferenceHelper appPreferencesHelper) {
    return appPreferencesHelper;
}
```

Differently you could use `@Binds`

```
@Binds
abstract PreferenceHelper providePreferencesHelper(AppPreferenceHelper appPreferencesHelper);
```

for that you are gonna need a different `abstract @Module`, tho